# ow to access a DOM element without template variable angular 2

Tags: angular

To add functionality to third-party components many times the only way is to access the dom.
As you can access these elements if they do not have a template variable #name

Comment: document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You can just use good 'ol JQuery, or querySelector ( "classOrIdName" ) and/or querySelectorAll ( "classOrIdName" )

CSS Selectors still work just fine in Angular 12(3?)4, provided there is something to select (the usual class, tag, id, etc).

This one is VERY well documented.

Comment: I will try with jquery because queryselector has problems with AOT compilation, thanks for your help